# Is it allowed to cache multiple Interstitials in AdMob loaded at the same time for different activities in the same app?

Tags: android, singleton, admob, interstitial

Is it allowed to cache multiple AdMob interstitials instances in different activities for the same app? i.e. the MainActivity will cache an interstitial for only that activity. The context of this MainActivity will be passed to a singleton class, that should provide another interstitial available to be shown in the rest of activities of the app, and both instances are loaded at the same time.

Comment: You can't use context of an Activity inside other Activity.

Comment: I am not using context in another activity but in a singleton class that inherits from Application not from Activity although, yes, multiple activities have access to that singleton class.

Comment: Yes, you are trying to use Context of MainActivity inside another activity using it as singleton. It does not matter it's singleton or not issue is you can't use another Activity's context to infilate layout and add views to it.

Comment: You can use Context of Application as a Singleton but you will get RuntimeException if i remember right. Layout of an Activity or Fragment should be infilated using the context of current activity.

Comment: Singleton context of Application or getApplicationContext() is good for accessing resources. Layouts should use Activity.this method for infilating views.

Comment: You are right. Actually, instead of showing the interstitial in those activities who use the singleton class, the interstitial is only shown when returning to the main activity, but those secondary activities are necessary to control the flow of showing the ads. But regarding the first question, is it allowed to make two AdRequests for interstitials using AdMob?